# How to write hapi code for a specific local URL

Tags: java, search, hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I am presently using HAPI FHIR server for implementation.

Presently I have HAPI code for below  AND Query which is working fine.

http://127.0.0.1:8080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver/fhir/Organization?name=SIMPLY&address=SIMPLY

Bundle bundle = client.search().forResource(Organization.class).where(Organization.ADDRESS.contains().value("SIMPLY")).where(Organization.NAME.contains().value("SIMPLY")).returnBundle(Bundle.class).execute();

Can anyone help me with the

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver/fhir/Organization?name=SIMPLY,address=SIMPLY
```

Comment: Is your question how to declare the `http://127.0.0.1:8080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver/fhir/` bit?

Comment: hello @LloydMcKenzie , I looking for HAPI code to implement the OR condition for SearchParameters name , address for Organization resource,  as shown in your URL where name and address are separated via comma